# Laravel eloquent in dedicated relation table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

[image: eloquent laravel]

How to get multiple row from tags table using single id_post in eloquent.

Comment: It looks like a `pivot` table, how did you get the `id_post` can you share more information and your `model`s as well ?

Comment: It's much better to delete questions you no longer want after the comments stream has finished - otherwise you will find that you have wasted people's time, since they have composed a comment they can no longer post.

Answer (score 0):

```
$posts = Post::with('tags')->get();
foreach($posts as $post) {
    $tags = $post->tags;
}
```

Now, this is assuming that you've setup your models as 'Post' and 'Tag'

If your Post model, you should have a `tags` method that says where to find the tags, something like:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tag');
}
```

Comment: The relations between posts and tags are stored in separate table. This query has no relation with "posts_tags" table.
I have a id of "posts" table. I have to query in "posts_tags" table to get hasMany('posts_tags') row and simultaneously get the corresponding rows for each "tags" row.

Comment: You need to use many to many relation http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many

Comment: my mistake, rushed through this while I was waiting for a task to run... fixed up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set a Many to many relation in your post and tag model:

Your Post Model:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tag');
}
```

Your Tag model:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Post');
}
```

And then you can use Eloquent to get all tags associated to your post_id:

```
$tags = Post:find($post_id)->tags()->get();
```